# What does "near the seat of" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Two centuries later (1438) a Birgittine convent was founded in
> Nådendal (Naantali), **near the seat of** the bishopric in Åbo,
> flourishing for a brief period before the Lutheran Reformation swept
> across northern Europe in the sixteenth century. (bolds my me)
>
> - A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

I think that the author means that the convent founded was serving "under the rule of" bishopric. Is this correct? Or does it mean geographically, founded convent was located somewhere near the juricdiction of that bishopric?

Comment: Your second conjecture is correct - the use of **seat** to mean a base or centre. See 
 https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seat

Comment: Also, a bishop has their official seat (throne) in a cathedral (named from the Latin _cathedra_, a seat).

Comment: So the text here tells about geographical proximity between this cathedra (where the bishop sits) and convent right?

Comment: @KateBunting The Latin _cathedra_ itself comes from Ancient Greek (κατά - “down” + ἕδρα -seat). But it is true that the English got it from Latin, not directly from Greek.

Comment: Yes, it says that the convent was near the cathedral.

Comment: Thanks you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A region under the jurisdiction of a bishop is a "bishopric" or "diocese", or "episcopal see".  Each diocese is centred on a city with a cathedral, and this cathedral said to be the "seat" of the bishop.

So the convent was near the cathedral of Åbo (The Swedish name for Turku). Indeed, it is about 15km from the cathedral to Naantali.